# Prestashop theme version naming

Tags: prestashop

Can two versions of the same theme exist at the same time?

I would like to have same name but different versions in `config.yaml`. It seems to me that this is not possible since theme's name and folder must be same.

It's mainly when doing local theme development but on live production website that would be useful too since you could go back to previous version quickly if something goes wrong.

How to generally avoid naming themes like `my-theme-1-1-3`?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need different versions of the same theme with the same name.

What you need and what is recommended is to have one or more child themes.

The parent stays the same but you extend and change it using whatever name you want (and a separate directory for it).

You can create any number of child themes all having the same parent theme and inheriting from it.

See here [Prestashop child themes](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/template-inheritance/parent-child-feature/)